# How can I make my select * from join table statement permanent

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a JOIN statement permanent
Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT B.*, A.name FROM users A JOIN comments B ON A.userID=B.userID
```

Comment: What do you mean? SELECT queries don't modify the database, they just return data from it.

Comment: Shouldn't `ON comments.userID=comments.userID` be `ON comments.userID=users.userID`?

Comment: @Fajrwajr I'm not understanding. Do you want to create a table from the result set of this query? In which case it would be CREATE TABLE PERM_TABLE AS SELECT B.*, A.name 
FROM users A 
    JOIN comments B ON A.userID=B.userID;

Answer (score 1):

could be you are looking for a view

```
 create  view  my_view as 
 SELECT comments.*, users.name 
 FROM users 
 JOIN comments ON comments.userID=comments.userID
```

then you can use

```
 select * from my_view;
```

Comment: A view isn't  'permanent'  - I don't understand the question.